# search either by first name or last name

Tags: php, civicrm

I have two text boxes for first name and last name. Admin can search records either by first name or last name from respective text boxes. I make an api calls sending first name or last name to fetch records.

What I want is to provide just one textbox. Here admin can type either firstname or last name or full name. How can I sort out these names and make an api call.
if user has typed only first name then i send only first name in api call. If he has provided both name I send both names. I first check in which textbox he has typed and accordingly I make api calls

```
$params = array( 
    'return' => array(
        'first_name',
        'display_name',
        'image_URL',
        'last_name',
        'phone',
        'email'
    ),
    'version' => 3,
    'sequential' => 1,
    'limit' => 25,
    'first_name' = "Shrinidhi",
    'last_name' = "Kulkarni"
);

$contact = civicrm_api('Contact', 'get', $params);
```

Comment: If you have one textbox and the user types in "Ryan", how would the system possibly know if that is a first or last name?  Could be "Ryan Smith" or "Jack Ryan"

Comment: It is not any clearer.  Without thinking about code, just from a logical perspective, try to answer my question.  Either you are not asking what you really intend, or what you are asking is impossible.

Comment: @EricJ. Check the code now and the edited question

Comment: @EricJ. Is the problem clear now?

Comment: Is your query running with "and" clause in sql, which framework are you using

Comment: Can the user type only the last name, without the first name?

Comment: @zan Its not like that. I pass the parameters in array which act as WHERE clause in SQL. See the example above. I am sending 'first_name'=>Shrinidhi which is like select * from contacts where firstname="Shrinidhi"

Comment: @EricJ. Yes... at that time I only send last name like I remove first_name=Shrinidhi from $params array

Comment: @EricJ. I first check if user has typed first name or last name. And then push the name which he has typed into array and make api call..

Comment: @ShrinidhiKulkarni just make the custom query with civicrm to meet your requirement

Comment: @zan Can u elaborate your answer.. I dont know much about civicrm. This is my first project on civicrm. U mean to say modify or add code in civicrm to handle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT 'first_name','display_name','image_URL','last_name','phone','email' from Contact where 'shrinidhi' in (first_name,last_name)";
CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery($sql);
```

For further reference:
http://www.vedaconsulting.co.uk/civicrm/civicrm-executing-custom-sql/

Comment: My problem is how r u going to differentiate firstname and last name.. Right now i have different text boxes for first name and last name.. So there is no problem .. I want to provide only one text box like full name..

Comment: @ShrinidhiKulkarni,I can get the output that matches the input from user(One input box) against the database . Why you want to check first name or last name , where all matters is getting the matched record.  see Query Modified

Comment: ok.. I got it.. Your solution seems correct. Can u tell me the exact civicrm file where I have to make changes? Thank u for the solution by the by

Answer (score 1):

You should use a query like this one:

```
SELECT CONCAT(firstname, lastname) AS fullname FROM tablename WHERE fullname LIKE '%input%';
```

So you can find both firstname and lastname with one input field.

Enjoy your code!

Answer (score 0):

You can check for a whitesapce in the input value and extract the first name and last name using the position of the whitespace. If there is no whitespace in the input value you should call the API using first name only.